# Cannot upgrade ubuntu from 20.10 to 21.04

Tags: apt, upgrade

I keep getting the below errors when I try to upgrade Ubuntu:

```
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security InRelease                                                                                                                                         
Err https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu groovy InRelease                                                                                                                                            
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7EA0A9C3F273FCD8                                                                                      
Fetched 43.3 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                                                                                            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease                                                                                                                                                   
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates InRelease                                                                                                                                           
Get:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu groovy InRelease [43.3 kB]                                                                                                                                
Err https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu groovy InRelease                                                                                                                                            
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7EA0A9C3F273FCD8                                                                                      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security InRelease                                                                                                                                         
Fetched 43.3 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                                                                                            

Error during update 

A problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of 
network problem, please check your network connection and retry. 


Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
```

Any suggestions?

I have tried to change mirrors go wired network but each time the exact same error above.

Comment: Get rid of the docker repos.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't install docker on my ubuntu, because of a "NO\_PUBKEY 7EA0A9C3F273FCD8" error in apt-get update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1347880/cant-install-docker-on-my-ubuntu-because-of-a-no-pubkey-7ea0a9c3f273fcd8-err)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix the GPG error "NO\_PUBKEY"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)